# Divergence of an iterative map variant.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-linear-algebra

The problem at hand.

Let $M$ be a matrix from $R^p$ to $R^p$ with $\rho(M)<1$. Let $(b_{n})$ be a divergent. Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is divergent, where $x_n=Mx_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$.

Not really sure how to tackle this. What I've tried is to unwind and get $x_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}M^{i}b_{n-1-i}+m^{n-1}x_1$ then try and show that it's not Cauchy. But I'm not having much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by contradiction.

Let us write the relationship under the following form:

$$x_n-Mx_{n-1}=b_{n-1}$$

Were $(x_n)$ convergent to $L$, the LHS of (1) would converge to $L-ML$ whereas the RHS diverges.